# SQLAlchemy printing (def __str__(self):) - UnicodeDecodeError

Tags: python

My class definition causing the problem:

```
class Auction(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'auctions'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)    
    owner = Column(String, nullable=False)

    # a lot of other not important attributes 

    def __str__(self):
        return u"<Auction(id={0}, owner={1})>".format(self.id, self.owner)

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.__str__()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.__str__()
```

My engine:

```
engine = create_engine('sqlite:///somepath', encoding='utf8', echo=True)
```

Problematic code:

```
s = Session() #using the engine above
for a in s.query(Auction).all():
    print a
```

It prints just fine, unless a unicode char is used (in `.owner` or `.owner_realm`).

Error:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xf8' in position 70: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I tried also to do `print unicode(a)` but that doesn't help either. Similarly, parsing `self.owner` as `unicode(self.owner)` did not help either.

I do populate it just fine - I use `unicode(some_owner)` to populate an auction instance, the problem is only with printing.